# Is there a way to extract the uuid from a dSYM on linux?

Tags: linux, centos, uuid, dwarf, dsym

Is there a way to extract the uuid from a dSYM on linux? And specifically on CentOS if it's possible.

I tried to use dwarfdump, mediainfo, exiftool, llvm-dwarfdump, and I Couldn't extract it.

dwarfdump commands results without output.
llvm-dwarfdump -u doesn't exist. Other arguments of llvm-dwarfdump didn't produce the uuid.
With the rest of the tools I couldn't produce the uuid.

It there some other tool? Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: llvm-otool can be used

```
$ llvm-otool -l foo.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/foo
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedfacf 16777223          3  0x00          10     9       2664 0x00000000
Load command 0
     cmd LC_UUID
 cmdsize 24
    uuid 06226c4f-5cd4-4f01-a3a2-4162ebd4b8fd
...
```